# Python Pandas regex outputting NaN

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column with characters like this (supposed to be a dictionary but became strings after scraping into a CSV):

```
{"id":307,"name":"Drinks","slug":"food/drinks"...`
```

I'm trying to extract the values for "name", so in this case it would be "Drinks".

The code I have right now (shown below) keeps outputting NaN for the entire dataframe.

```
df['extracted_category'] = df.category.str.extract('("name":*(?="slug"))')
```

What's wrong with my regex? Thanks!

Comment: This will get the value of name in group 1 `"name":"([^"]+)"` but can you parse it as json and get the value for key name?

Comment: Hello, i think you don't need the look forward clause as ``?=``. Instead of that you can update your regex and try for this one : ``("name":*("\w*"))``.

Testing on https://regex101.com/r/xdHD8t/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to convert it into dataframe you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and `pd.Series` for that like

```
# sample dataframe
df
                                          category
0  {"id":307,"name":"Drinks","slug":"food/drinks"}

df.category.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(eval(x)))
    id    name         slug
0  307  Drinks  food/drinks
```

Or convert only string to dictionary using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
df['category'] = df.category.apply(eval)

df.category.str["name"]
0    Drinks
Name: category, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ellie check also this approach:

```
x = {"id":307,"name":"Drinks","slug":"food/drinks"}
result = [(key, value) for key, value in x.items() if key.startswith("name")]
print(result)
[('name', 'Drinks')]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, firstly the outer-most parenthesis in ("name":*(?="slug")) need to go because these represent the first group and the extracted value would then be equal to the first group which is not where the value of 'name' lies.

A simpler regex to try would be "name":"(\w*)" (Note: make sure to keep the part of the regex that you want to be extracted inside the parenthesis). This regex looks for the following string:

```
    "name":"
```

and extracts all the alphabets that follow it (\w*) before stopping at another double quotation mark.

You can test your regex at: https://regex101.com/